# stuck at setting secret key in django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, secret-key

structure = mysite

- mysite
- settings - base.py, deployment.py, production.py
- **init**.py
- asgi.py
- urls.py
- wsgi.py

base.py has all the base settings.
deployment.py has code

```
from .base import *

DEBUG = True

SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']
```

after running py manage.py runserver --settings=mysite.settings.development
i got the error as follows :

```
(venv) C:\Users\Pc\PycharmProjects\mysite>py manage.py runserver --settings=mysite.settings.development
import export
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Pc\PycharmProjects\mysite\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Pc\PycharmProjects\mysite\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "C:\Users\Pc\PycharmProjects\mysite\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 76, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\Pc\PycharmProjects\mysite\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 63, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Users\Pc\PycharmProjects\mysite\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 142, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Users\Pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Rohan\PycharmProjects\mysite\mysite\settings\development.py", line 5, in <module>
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']
  File "C:\Users\Rohan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\os.py", line 675, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'SECRET_KEY'
```

any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

That suggests you didn't add SECRET_KEY into your os environment.

You could do the following:

1. Add the secret key into your os (seems you are using Windows): `setx SECRET_KEY <your secret key>` in command promt.
2. In your settings.py, add this `SECRET_KEY = os.getenv("SECRET_KEY")`